# Variable input read from stdin

Tags: c, input, stdin

I have a doubt for example if i have an input like this :

```
5 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4
2 3
1 2 3
```

Where the first number means the different "toys" there are to attribute to each kid which corresponds to the second number which is four and by consequence to the number of lines that represents each kid and the toys they want ...

How would i read an input like this in ansi C?
With the use of `strtok`? or is there any other simpler way to do it?

i could do it with something like this

```
char line [250];
char * tok;
char *ptr = line;


while((scanf("%s",line)!= EOF){

    while ((tok = strtok(ptr, " ")) != NULL)
    {
        pseudo part
        //convert to int
        //add to array

    }

}
```

but is there any easier way to do this input without using tok?
Thanks ...

Comment: Is the origin of `ptr` supposed to be riddle?

Comment: Have you read the man page for `strtok`?  Successive calls use NULL instead of the original value.

Comment: i gave that as an example like i stated i dont want an alternative using strtok like i stated above one more time i want another way to do it ...

Comment: `scanf("%s", line)` isn't going to read a line, it's going to read a whitespace delimited string, so you don't need `strtok`.

Comment: if you at least read how the input works you would understand why the use of strtok....

Comment: I did read how the input works.  You were the one asking if there was a way to do this without using `strtok`.  I was just pointing out your misuse of `scanf`. Also, `scanf` will work given "clever" format strings that detect the newlines; however, @SHR's answer will be easier (although I would use the `for` loop pattern from the `strtok` manpage which eliminates the need for `ptr`), you still need to convert the tokens to integers with `atoi`, `strtoul`, or `sscanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend a classic `fgets()/sscanf()` combination.

Read in one line at a time.  Good error checking available.  Use `"%n"` to know where to begin the next scanning for the next toy.

```
char buffer[250];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL)
  HandleEOF();
int toys, kids;
int cnt = sscanf(buffer, "%d%d", &toys, &kids);
if (cnt != 2 || toys <= 0 || kids <= 0)
  Handle_BadToysKids(cnt);
int kid_wants[kids][toys] = { 0 };

for (int k = 0; k < kids; k++) {
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL)
    HandleEOF();
  char *p = buffer;
  int want;
  int n;
  while ((cnt = sscanf(p, "%d %n", &want, &n)) == 1) {
    if (want <= 0 || want > toys)
      Handle_BadWant(want);
    kid_wants[k][want - 1] = 1;
    p += n;
  }
}
```

Improvements:
Use `size_t toys, kids` and `"%zu"`.
Use sentinel to check for extra junk on a line:
`int ch; int cnt = sscanf(buffer, "%d%d %c", &toys, &kids, &ch);`
Check `*p` at end of `while` loop - it should be `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) to read a line, not scanf. 
scanf will read only till the first white space.
(better to use `fgets` just because it is safer than [`gets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/))

like this:

```
ptr = fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
```

Your `strtok` will work, if you set ptr to NULL after the first call. 
Anyway, it is better to add more white spaces like: `" \r\n\t"`

```
//assume ptr = line had been set by fgets...
char* tok;
do{
   const char* whitespaces = " \r\n\t";
   tok = strtok(ptr, whitespaces);
   ptr = NULL;//till next fgets
   if(tok){
      //got more number  
   }
}while(tok);
```